# Subdomain mapping to another external subdomain

Tags: dns, mapping, cname

I'm trying to map help.domain1.com to help.domain2.com. I've seen this on UserVoice. They let you map something.yourdomain.com to something.uservoice.com.

On domain1.com I've set up a CNAME to help.domain2.com.

It works fine but when I open help.domain1.com I get the content of domain2.com instead of help.domain2.com.

After some experimenting I've realized that this is an expected behavior.

So my question is what do I have to do on domain2.com (or maybe on domain1.com?) to have it show content of subdomain "help.domain2.com" when I navigate help.domain1.com?

(I'm using Plesk and the OS is Windows Server 2003)

Comment: What do you see if you visit help.domain2.com?

Comment: I want to map support.maindomain.com (win) to support.internaldomain.com (linux). Just for estatic reason because the name of internaldomain has nothing to do with the content of main domain. But we run our ticketing system on private server.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that you have checked that visiting support.internaldomain.com returns the correct content, in order to rule that out as the cause.

Comment: Give real domain names so that we can see them. Otherwise, it is only guesswork.

Comment: In maindomain.com configuration (I do not know Plesk so I won't provide details), just add a CNAME *from* support.maindomain.com *to* support.internaldomain.com. Or, just add an address record *from* support.maindomain.com *to* the IP address of support.maindomain.com (there are pros and cons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. One way would be to use a mod_rewrite rule on domain2.com and do a redirect if referrer is domain1.com. Or to assign a dedicated IP address.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here; trying to map sub.domain_a.com to sub.domain_b.com. I made a subdomain on domian_a and redirect it to sub.domain_b.com and it works but of course, the link on the address bar is also changing wich is not what I'm tryign to achive. If I understood, you made a CNAME record on domain_a, like `sub.domain_a.com. 14400 IN CNAME sub.domain_b.com` and it worked for you? Did you had to wait for propagation or not?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem for the last couple of days, and just found the solution...

In /etc/apache2/site-available/default, I had two virtual hosts, first one was for my domain, and the second one was for my sub domain. All I had to do was reverse the order of the virtual host blocks, placing the sub domain in front of the domain, and it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1.1 uses the `Host:` header to figure out which site is being requested, should there be more than one site hosted on the same IP address.

You need to ensure that the second (target) web-server is configured to expect incoming HTTP requests with the original URI in them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how to do this in windows but in apache you just need to setup a virtual host to redirect it from the main domain to your subdomain.

you do not say if you are using IIS or apache or what the webserver is.

I imagine that what you need to do is setup a new website in IIS (not a virtual directory) and in the website tab click on advanced and edit the entry in there so that the "host header name" is the subdomain you want.

Jon Hawkins